# How to compare border color of a cell in collection view (iOS, swift)

Tags: ios, swift, colors

I want to compare the color of my cells border like this:

```
if(cell.layer.borderColor == UIColor.blackColor().CGColor)
```

But i get a error.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
CGColorEqualToColor(cell.layer.borderColor, UIColor.blackColor().CGColor)
```

You can't compare with the `==` operator two `CGColor`